# Как сделать сортировку по алфавиту,и по дате на с++

Tags: c++

Добрый вечер товарищи!

Есть у меня файл где записанные тикер (краткое название), дата и стоимость акций.Нужно сделать сортировку по алфавиту,но если есть одинаковые буквы в название то нужно отсортировать их по дате создания.
Можете мне рассказать как сделать эти две сортировки

Вот сам код

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

ifstream in("ticker.txt");
ofstream out("output.txt");

struct ticker{
    string name;
    char data[40], stock[40];
    void print();
};

void ticker::print(){
    out << name  << '\t'<<data << '\t' << stock << '\t' << endl;
}

void sort(ticker *a, int n) 
{
    ticker tmp;
    for (int i = 1, j; i<n; ++i)
    {
        tmp = a[i]; 
        for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && a[j].name > tmp.name; --j)
            a[j + 1] = a[j];
        a[j + 1] = tmp;
    }

}

int main(){
    int n = 0;
    ticker a[20];
    while (in.peek() != EOF){
        in >> a[n].name >> a[n].data >>  a[n].stock;
        n++;
    }
    sort(a, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        a[i].print();
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Буду благодарен вашей помощи

Comment: а почему одно поле  C++ строка а другие массивы символов?..

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю можно написать

```
bool operator<(const ticker& t1, const ticker& t2)
{
    if (t1.name < t2.name)
        return true;
    else if (t1.name == t2.name && strcmp(t1.data, t2.data) < 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

и используйте `sort` из STL.
Ну и подключите `cstring`.

Comment: А как вызывать этот operator;

Comment: @Артем Теперь если есть два обьекта ticker a и b, то можно просто писать a < b.